# Missing title bars of every window

Tags: gnome, metacity, titlebar

Recently I did re-install empathy, and installed Pidgin. I don't think this is related to gnome system.

I don't know what else I did, but all the window's title bars are gone. Basically I can't move the windows.

I tried 'metacity --replace', and by doing so the title bars appear as normal but it crashes the X system eventually. After reboot, I don't see title bars again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I got titlebars back. 

I wanted to reduce windows effects, so I unchecked 'animation' from compizconfig settings manager. I checked it again, and I got the title bars back.

Every time I change something in compiz configurations, something crashes. It is too fragile nowadays.

Comment: Metacity is being deprecated in favor of Mutter. Try run `mutter --replace`. Else try Fluxbox or something.

Comment: If it's compiz try to delete any bad files rm -R .config/compiz-1 .compiz-1 .gconf/apps/compiz-1 .gconf/apps/compizconfig then reboot

Comment: If resetting compiz to default settings fixed the problem you can post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

it's most probably because of compiz.. I got that problem when I tried to use compiz with emerald.. try using fusion-icon and reload the window manager by right clicking and it'll solve the problem...